# Trying to wire autocomplete to google suggest

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm looking to add autocomplete to my site, https://www.headlineintime.com/, using the Kendo UI, and want to wire it into Google Suggest since the news search box would have relevant content across the web.  Any ideas how this should be wired?  I tried using this:

```
   $('#search').kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Search ...",
        suggest: true,
        select: function (e) {
            $('#btnSearch').trigger('click');
        },
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox",
                    data: onAdditionalData,
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                }
            },
        })
```

but this doesn't seem to work.  The problem is that it doesn't correctly show the Google suggest items:

[image]

And looking at the JSON coming back from Google in Fiddler looks like:

[image]

Any suggestions (no pun intended)?  Thanks for any help!

-Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what I was missing.  I needed the schema setting to have the parse attribute point to the second element of the result, which is the list.  Below is the complete code for the autocomplete:

```
        $('#search').kendoAutoComplete({
        minLength: 3,
        filter: "startswith",
        placeholder: "Search ...",
        suggest: true,
        select: function (e) {
            $('#btnSearch').trigger('click');
        },
        dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "https://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox",
                    data: onAdditionalData,
                    type: "get",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                }
            },
            schema: {
                parse: function(data) {
                    return data[1];
                }
            }
        })
    });
```

You can see it working correctly at https://www.headlineintime.com:

[image]